# error when i try to debug my program, using Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I try to debug the following error apear:
Error 1 Two output file names resolved to the same output path: "obj\Debug\ImportaLM.UserControl1.resources"
I don´t have any clue what is happen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error : Two output file names resolved to the same output path: "obj\Debug\Project1.Form1.resources"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758239/error-two-output-file-names-resolved-to-the-same-output-path-obj-debug-proje)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739794/two-output-file-names-resolved-to-the-same-output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually occurs when you have two .resx files that point at the same page, as a result of a file being renamed. Delete the old .resx file and rebuild