# Two output file names resolved to the same output path VB.net

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I have a problem with VB.net.

Error message:

> Two output file names resolved to the same output path: "obj\x86\Debug\FinalProject.Form1.resources"

What's wrong with my project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error : Two output file names resolved to the same output path: "obj\Debug\Project1.Form1.resources"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758239/error-two-output-file-names-resolved-to-the-same-output-path-obj-debug-proje)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's probably beacause your form has `two .resx` if you try to delete one, the problem will be go

Check in your project for this and delete the odd one

Comment: thank's sir i've fixed my case, that is helpfull for me,

Comment: @garindaBurnama u r welcome..if this helped..mark it as answered

Comment: Great! Save my lots of time.